# Bitmap not updating/ showing old values

Tags: java, android, bitmap, screenshot, android-bitmap

I have a linear layout that has multiple fields that are to be filled by the user. The fields are to be filled with text or decimal numbers and they are all TextInputLayouts with one date picker. After the user has filled those fields I have a review button which once clicked shows a preview of all the values entered in an image view. I am showing the image by using bitmap and canvas and sending the bitmap as an argument to my material bottom sheet with the following code.

```
private Bitmap getDailySheetBitmap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(completeSheetLinearLayout.getWidth(), completeSheetLinearLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Log.d("Bitmap", "bitmap size: "+bitmap.getByteCount());
    completeSheetLinearLayout.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And the code for sending arg is

```
private void buildBottomSheet(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("Bitmap", bitmap);
    ViewDailySheet viewDailySheet = new ViewDailySheet();
    viewDailySheet.setArguments(args);
    viewDailySheet.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "DailySheet");
}
```

The problem is that after the user reviews the fields and changes are made to those fields and when the user again clicks on the review button, the bitmap with the same old values is shown. I have tried recycling bitmap, invalidating the view, requestLayout() and forceLayout() method. But none of it is helping.

This is the code that puts bitmap into image view.This is in bottom sheet dialog fragment.

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {
        bitmap = getArguments().getParcelable("Bitmap");
        binding.dailySheetImage.invalidate();
        binding.dailySheetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        getArguments().clear();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: There is no code that puts the bitmap in the imageview.

Comment: What is not updating? The bitmap or the imageview?

Comment: What is ViewDailySheet?

Comment: ViewDailySheet is the bottomSheetDialogFragment where I am showing the image. I think the bitmap is not getting updated. Suppose if  I have written "Joe" in the name text field, and if I again change the name to "john"  without closing the app/activity, then the screenshot(bitmap) still shows the name as "Joe" rather than "John"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bitmap only captures what it thinks has changed. If the text field(not the data, just UI) is not changed it will show the same text field value as before. So I refreshed the whole layout as it would re-draw the entire layout by the following code.

```
private void refreshView() {
    completeSheetLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    completeSheetLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I put this code just before creating the bitmap.